# How to transpose time-series by unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data looks like this:

```
    Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id
0    1     2018-01-01 00:00:05.523 40      1
1    2     2018-01-01 00:00:10.757 31.5    1
2    3     2018-01-01 00:00:15.507 25.5    1
                   ...
3    4     2018-01-01 00:00:05.743 35      2
4    5     2018-01-01 00:00:10.407 35.75   2
                   ...
```

I want to group data by `Group_Id` so that each unique value in `Group_Id` is one row, while transposing the timestamps into a time series with each timestamp in a column like below:

```
            x0      x1      x2      x3      x4      x5      ...
1           40      31.05   25.5    25.5    25.5    25      ...
2           35      35.75   36.5    36.5    36.5    36.5    ...
⋮           ⋮       ⋮        ⋮       ⋮       ⋮        ⋮
```

Then I want to rename the timestamps according to time order, ie. the `x0` replacing the first timestamp, `x1` the second ...

I checked the `df.pivot_table` documentation and couldn't find a relevant function that sorts time series. And discussion on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) did not help me with this problem.

Comment: You were reading the correct solution. Check out question 10 in the discussion. In your case, `Data` is `B`, `Group_Id` is `A`.

Comment: I checked question 10. Why do they have to insert 0 here? `df2.insert(0, 'count', df2.groupby('A').cumcount())`

Comment: Which part of the code sort `B` (ie. `Data`)? Thanks

Comment: 1. Insert syntax: `df.insert(location, name, values)`. You don't even need `insert`. You can make do with just `df['count'] = df.groupby('Group_Id').cumcount()`. 2. The question implicitly says you need to do `df.pivot(index='Group_Id', columns='count', values='Data')`.

Comment: Use this: `new_df=df.copy()
new_df['Timestamp']='x'+new_df.groupby('Group_Id')['Timestamp'].cumcount().astype(str)
new_df.pivot_table(index='Group_Id',columns='Timestamp',values='Data')`

Comment: then if you want.... `new_df.columns.name=None`

Comment: Thanks @ansev. may I know what `new_df.columns.name=None` does here? I ran and compare the code it didn't seem to bring any change

Comment: remove Timestamp as the name of the columns after pivoting

Comment: @ansev Checked my code again and still don't see any change:/

Comment: If this doesn't matter to you, just don't use it.

Comment: you should see that the name 'Timestamp' disappears at the top left of the dataframe

Comment: @ansev Yeah that is what I wanted to do, but it refuses to disappear...

Comment: @ansev And some values are `NaN`, any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @ansev I notice that pivoting distorts the order which gives `Timestamp x0 x1 x10 x100 x1000 x1001 x1002 x1003 x1004 x1005 x1006 x1007 x1008 x1009 x101 x1010 x1011 x1012 ...` for the column headings

Comment: There are larger groups than others, it is normal for NaN...

Comment: @ansev Yeah no worries it's sorted, but the order of indexing is still confusing...

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Can you test `df['Timestamp']=df.groupby('Group_Id')['Timestamp'].cumcount()

df = df.pivot(index='Group_Id',columns='Timestamp',values='Data').add_prefix('x')` ?