# How to extract data from df2 based on datetime data in df1 in python

Tags: python, pandas

The question here is that I am using 2 datasets: `df1` has all time log data for a few years; `df2` has data of incidents that happen at a specific point of time. I need to extract from `df1` a segment of one-week data **right before** the datetime of the `IncidentTime` in `df2`(thus `IncidentTime` is the end time of a 7-day period for a particular `Group_Id`).

> Note:
>   A `Group_Id` may have more than 1 incidents(ie. there may be multiple rows in `df2` with the same `Group_Id`).

Here are the datasets:

df1

```
      Timestamp           Group_Id      Data
2013-10-20 00:00:05.143    11           14
2013-10-21 00:05:10.377    11           15
2013-10-22 14:22:15.501    11           19
                   ...
2016-03-05 00:00:05.743    101          21
2017-12-24 00:00:10.407    101          33
                   ...
```

df2

```
IncidentTime       Group_Id
27/10/13 16:08      11
03/12/16 16:11      2
24/10/14 12:08      11
04/07/17 08:00      100
03/04/13 14:10      26
15/11/18 17:00      46
11/02/19 00:20      101
```

Then create a new column in final data for `IncidentTime`(it'll be the same for a `Group_Id` each time). For example, `Group_Id = 11` has `IncidentTime` of `27/10/13 16:08`, thus we take all data from `df1` for `Group_Id = 11` where its `Timestamp` lie between `20/10/13 16:08` and `27/10/13 16:08`. So that our final data `df3` has the 7-day data corresponding to its own `IncidentTime` for all `Group_Id`:

df3

```
IncidentTime       Group_Id       Timestamp             Data
27/10/13 16:08      11        2013-10-20 19:10:05.143    14
27/10/13 16:08      11        2013-10-21 00:05:10.377    15
27/10/13 16:08      11        2013-10-22 14:22:15.501    19
                                  ...
27/10/13 16:08      11        2013-10-27 05:22:15.501    20
                                  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can canvert columns to datetimes first and then create `IncidentTime_start` column by subtract 7 days and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join:

```
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df2['IncidentTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['IncidentTime'], dayfirst=True)
df2['IncidentTime_start'] = df2['IncidentTime'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=7)

df = df2.merge(df1, on='Group_Id', how='outer')
```

---

```
print (df)
         IncidentTime  Group_Id  IncidentTime_start               Timestamp  \
0 2013-10-27 16:08:00        11 2013-10-20 16:08:00 2013-10-20 00:00:05.143   
1 2013-10-27 16:08:00        11 2013-10-20 16:08:00 2013-10-21 00:05:10.377   
2 2013-10-27 16:08:00        11 2013-10-20 16:08:00 2013-10-22 14:22:15.501   
3 2016-12-03 16:11:00         2 2016-11-26 16:11:00                     NaT   
4 2014-10-24 12:08:00        40 2014-10-17 12:08:00                     NaT   
5 2017-07-04 08:00:00       100 2017-06-27 08:00:00                     NaT   
6 2013-04-03 14:10:00        26 2013-03-27 14:10:00                     NaT   
7 2018-11-15 17:00:00        46 2018-11-08 17:00:00                     NaT   
8 2019-02-11 00:20:00       101 2019-02-04 00:20:00 2016-03-05 00:00:05.743   
9 2019-02-11 00:20:00       101 2019-02-04 00:20:00 2017-12-24 00:00:10.407   

    Data  
0   14.0  
1   15.0  
2   19.0  
3    NaN  
4    NaN  
5    NaN  
6    NaN  
7    NaN  
8   21.0  
9  331.0
```

And then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = (df[df['Timestamp'].between(df['IncidentTime_start'], df['IncidentTime'])]
                                                        .drop('IncidentTime_start', axis=1))
print (df)
         IncidentTime  Group_Id               Timestamp  Data
1 2013-10-27 16:08:00        11 2013-10-21 00:05:10.377  15.0
2 2013-10-27 16:08:00        11 2013-10-22 14:22:15.501  19.0
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael something went wrong: after merging all my `Timestamp` become `NaT`. Is it better to slice `df1` by `Timestamp` between `IncidentTime ` & `IncidentTime_start `? Then concat all subset of individual `Group_Id ` together as they are of the same format.

Comment: It returned "Empty DataFrame" with only the headings for `df`. I'm thinking maybe it's because that `Group_Id` is not unique identifier in `df1` and `df2`, that's why we cannot merge?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - is same `print (df1['Group_Id'].dtype)` and `print (df2['Group_Id'].dtype)` ?

Comment: ..df... is `int64`; ...df2... is `float64`

Comment: @nilsinelabore - one idea - `df1['Group_Id'] = df1['Group_Id'].astype(float)` before my solution should help...

Comment: is it okay to merge given `Group_Id` is not unique identifier? The `Data` column would be different. For instance, `Group_Id` =11

Comment: @nilsinelabore - yes, it is, but need same dtypes in `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: I just ran the new code again and it seems nothing has changed. `id` `Timestamp` `Data` are still `NaN` `NaT` `NaN` values.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - hmmm, it working nice with sample data, are you 100% sure there are matched dataframes per groups? Because if not, get missing values.

Comment: @jesrael there may not be a perfect match for each `Group_Id ` for `df1` and `df2`. Does it have to be? But I just need rows from `df1` whose `Timestamp` lie between the time interval in `df2`(from first 3 lines of your code) which is the main DataFrame.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - I understand, maybe try test more days like `20` in `df2['IncidentTime_start'] = df2['IncidentTime'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=20)`  if some match. Seems data related problem, solution working nice.

Comment: would you mind briefly explaining why `df1&2` can merge event though `Group_Id` is not unique and what it means by `dayfirst=True`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore -- oops - first need `df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])` no dayfirst=True, because it means if format `DD/MM/YYYY` - days are first, then months. So for second it is necessary.

Comment: I see. And if merge `on='Group_Id'`, how does it work for 2 `Group_Id` 11 in `df2` and multiple `Group_Id`11 in `df1`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - It create all possible combinations per groups - like each group `11` from df1 repeat all rows for `11` group from df2, check `print (df)` in answer for verify it.